# Codegniter - Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(mathches)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web

I'm learning how to create a login page but I'm having trouble in this section

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?= set_value('email'); ?>">
        <?= form_error('email', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
            <?= form_error('password1', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password">
        </div>
```

Comment: What does your form validation code look like?

Comment: FYI, only add tags that are relevant to the issue. This has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.